# Possible recover/grab information stored on VRAM

Tags: data-recovery, vram

How can I recover information stored on VRAM, or is all information cleaned once the computer is reset? I was hoping to grab some textures and just generally interested in what, if any, data lurks on old graphic cards and if its possible to retrieve it?

Comment: The only data that remains on an old GPU after power is removed is a few hundred kilobytes of the GPU BIOS which is stored in an EEPROM. As grawity mentions GPU memory is volatile and contents will dissipate very quickly after power is removed.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, all GPUs use [dynamic RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory#Graphics_RAM), which can only retain data for very short durations. When the computer is powered on, it periodically refreshes DRAM contents; however, once you turn it off, everything quickly fades away.

Usually the data remains readable only for a few minutes (e.g. see [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack)) – certainly not months or years. Your box of old GPUs has nothing in it anymore.